# I got this error when using " YouTube Player API Reference for iframe Embeds"

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube-api

This is the message that I get:

> A cookie associated with a cross-site resource at http://youtube.com/ was set without the `SameSite` attribute. A future release of Chrome will only deliver cookies with cross-site requests if they are set with `SameSite=None` and `Secure`. You can review cookies in developer tools under Application>Storage>Cookies and see more details at https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5088147346030592 and https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5633521622188032.

Here is the code that i use

```
<div id="youtubevideo" data-video-url="{{youtubevideourl}}"></div>
<script>


$('[data-video-url]').each(function () {
var $self = $(this);
try {
    get_video_thumb($self.data('video-url'), function (image) { if (image != 
    null) { $self.css('background-image', 'url(' + image.url + ')'); 
    $self.append('<iframe id="FeaturedVideo" class="mdl-cell--hide" 
    width="100%" height="100%" />'); } });
    } catch (e) { }
 });
$('[data-video-url]').click(function () {
player = new YT.Player('youtubevideo', {
    height: '480',
    width: '100%',
    videoId: getYoutubeVideoId($(this).data('video-url')),
    events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady
    }
});
function onPlayerReady(event) {
    event.target.playVideo();
}
});

function get_video_thumb(url, callback) {
var id = get_video_id(url);
if (id['type'] == 'y') { return processYouTube(id);
} else if (id['type'] == 'v') {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://vimeo.com/api/v2/video/' + id['id'] + '.json',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function (data) {
            callback({ type: 'v', id: id['id'], url: data[0].thumbnail_large });
        }
    });
}
function processYouTube(id) {
    if (!id) { throw new Error('Unsupported YouTube URL');}
    callback({ type: 'y', id: id['id'], url: 'https://i2.ytimg.com/vi/' + 
id['id'] + '/hqdefault.jpg' });
}}

function getYoutubeVideoId(url) {
if (url.indexOf('youtube.com') > -1) {
    if (url.indexOf('v=') > -1) {id = url.split('v=')[1].split('&')[0]; }
    else if (url.indexOf('embed') > -1) { id = url.split('embed/') 
   [1].split('?')[0]; };
    return id;
}}

function get_video_id(url) {
var id;
var a;
if (url.indexOf('youtube.com') > -1) {
    if (url.indexOf('v=') > -1) {id = url.split('v=')[1].split('&')[0];}
    else if (url.indexOf('embed') > -1) { id = url.split('embed/')[1].split('?')[0];};
    return processYouTube(id);
}
else if (url.indexOf('youtu.be') > -1) {id = url.split(/v\/|v=|youtu\.be\//)[1].split(/[?&]/)[0];return processYouTube(id);}
else if (url.indexOf('vimeo.com') > -1) { if (url.match(/https?:\/\/(www\.)?vimeo.com\/(\d+)($|\/)/)) { id = url.split('/')[3];}
else if (url.match(/^vimeo.com\/channels\/[\d\w]+#[0-9]+/)) {id = url.split('#')[1];}
else if (url.match(/vimeo.com\/groups\/[\d\w]+\/videos\/[0-9]+/)) { id = url.split('/')[4];}
else if (url.match(/player.vimeo.com\/video\/[0-9]+/)) {id = url.split('/')[2];}
else { throw new Error('Unsupported Vimeo URL');}
}
else {throw new Error('Unrecognised URL');}
a = { type: 'v', id: id };
return a;
function processYouTube(id) {
    if (!id) { throw new Error('Unsupported YouTube URL');}
    a = { type: 'y', id: id };
    return (a); // default.jpg OR hqdefault.jpg
}}
</script>
```

Comment: The message you're receiving shows that the new cookie restrictions are not yet being applied in your browser. You may also get these messages for older cookies without any functionality being affected.

Can you share more information, like a code snippet or the page demonstrating the error, to help understand what you're trying to do?

Comment: I updated the code that i used can you please review and let me know anything that i missed

Comment: That's still only a snippet of the code, not enough to reproduce. Is everything actually working? The cookie message you're seeing is not currently affecting behaviour though.